# Unique value for every row of a column Jinja

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a pandas dataframe,

```
Columns: []
Index: [(2, TOPPER, 1, Ahmad Anis), (3, t2, 1, Ahmad Anis), (3, t2, 3, Ahmad Anis)]
```

Now, I want to send it to Jinja, to make a table.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(details.to_html(), features="lxml")
soup.find("tr").extract()

id = list(map(lambda a:a[0], details)) #list like [0,1,2,3]

html = str(soup)
return render_template('read_badge.html', tables=[html], id=id)
```

Now in Jinja

```html
{% for table,i_d in tables|zip(id)%}
   
    <form action="" method="post">
        
        <input type="submit" name='bid', value="{{i_d}}"> {{ table|safe }} </input>
        </form>

    {% endfor %}
```

I want to assign the badge_id as a value for each row of BADGE_ID column.

[image]

Means for 1st row/index, if we click on BADGE_ID, it should send a post request with value 2, if we click on next, it should send a post request with value 3.

Only for first column.

How to achieve this?

Comment: better create normal `links` instead of `form` - with `form` you would need `<button>` in every row to send only this row. And get it in `flask` as argument in `link` instead of `POST` - something similar to `/get/BADGE_ID`

Comment: How to create that normal link for my table?

Comment: `<a href="/get/{{ BADGE_ID }}"> ...row... </a>` or `<a href="/get/{{ BADGE_ID }}"> ...cell_in_row... </a>` but it needs also to change `views.py` to get requests `/get/BADGE_ID`

Comment: and send `details` to `Jinja` as normal data - not `to_html()` - and use `Jinja` to generate table. This way you can do with data whatever you like - using `to_html()` you only gets problems to format it

Comment: if you want to use `to_html()` then you should convert all values in `dataframe` to strings `<a href="/get/BADGE_ID"> ...value... </a>` and after that you should use `to_html`

Answer (score 0):

While creating table you can assign same class to every td like `<td class="myclass">{{i_d}}</td>`

Keep all of them in form and and add class to your form and in javascript , include jquery first.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.myclass').click(function(){
    $(".formclass").val($(this).text())
$('.formclass').trigger('submit')
}); });
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem makes `to_html()` which creates `HTML table` and later it is hard to do something with this table.

You should put `form` or better links `<a href=" .../BADGE_ID">value</a>` in every cell - but with `HTML table` it is big problem.

You could send `DataFrame` directly to `template` and create `<table>` using `for`-loops in template.

Full working example:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string
import pandas as pd
`

app = Flask(__name__)


data = [
    (2, 'TOPPER', 1, 'Ahmad Anis'),
    (3, 't2', 1, 'Ahmad Anis'),
    (3, 't2', 3, 'Ahmad Anis')
]
headers = ['BADGE_ID', 'BADGE_NAME', 'USER_ID', 'USER_NAME']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
#df.set_index(['BADGE_ID', 'BADGE_NAME', 'USER_ID', 'USER_NAME'], inplace=True)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template_string('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {background-color: #f88; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none}
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #fff}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #eee}
th a, td a {display: block; text-align: center}
thead th, tbody th a, td a {padding: 5px 15px}
tr:hover a {background-color: #8f8}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<thead>
<tr>
  <th>INDEX</th>
{% for name in headers %}
  <th>{{ name }}</th>
{% endfor %}
</t>
</thead>

<tbody>
{% for index, row in data.iterrows() %}
  <tr>
  <td><a href="/get/{{ row[0] }}">{{ index }}</a></td>
  {% for item in row %}
    <td><a href="/get/{{ row[0] }}">{{ item }}</a></td>
  {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>

</table>

</body>
</html>''', headers=headers, data=df)


@app.route('/get/<int:number>')
def get(number):
    result = df[ df['BADGE_ID'] == number]
    return render_template_string( f'<h1>BADGE_ID: {number}</h1>' + result.to_html() )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.debug = True 
    app.run()
```

---

Other method is to convert all data in `DataFrame` to strings

```
 <a href="/get/{BADGE_ID}">{item}</a>
```

and later use `to_html()`

```
def create_link(row):
    BADGE_ID = row['BADGE_ID']
    return row.apply(lambda item: f'<a href="/get/{BADGE_ID}">{item}</a>')

df_with_links = df.apply(create_link, axis=1)

html = df_with_links.to_html(escape=False)
```

Full working example:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

data = [
    (2, 'TOPPER', 1, 'Ahmad Anis'),
    (3, 't2', 1, 'Ahmad Anis'),
    (3, 't2', 3, 'Ahmad Anis')
]
headers = ['BADGE_ID', 'BADGE_NAME', 'USER_ID', 'USER_NAME']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
#df.set_index(['BADGE_ID', 'BADGE_NAME', 'USER_ID', 'USER_NAME'], inplace=True)

def create_link(row):
    BADGE_ID = row['BADGE_ID']
    return row.apply(lambda item: f'<a href="/get/{BADGE_ID}">{item}</a>')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    df_with_links = df.apply(create_link, axis=1)
    # after `to_links`
    #df_with_links.set_index(['BADGE_ID', 'BADGE_NAME', 'USER_ID', 'USER_NAME'], inplace=True)

    html = df_with_links.to_html(escape=False, border='0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0')
    return render_template_string('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {background-color: #f88; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0}
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #fff}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #eee}
th a, td a {display: block; text-align: center}
thead th, tbody th a, td a {padding: 5px 15px}
tr:hover a {background-color: #8f8}
</style>
</head>
<body>

{{ table | safe }}

</body>
</html>''', headers=headers, table=html)


@app.route('/get/<int:number>')
def get(number):
    result = df[ df['BADGE_ID'] == number]
    return render_template_string( f'<h1>BADGE_ID: {number}</h1>' + result.to_html() )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.debug = True 
    app.run()
```